# mailR not connecting to gmail server - R

Tags: r, sendmailr

I want to send an automated email using mailR. I cannot connect to the gmail server. I have allowed access to less secure apps on my gmail account, following suggestions by other users. This did not solve the issue.

Here is my code (password and email addresses are just examples):

```
library(mailR)
sender <- "example@gmail.com"
recipients <- c("example2@gmail.com")
send.mail(from = sender,
          to = recipients,
          subject = "Brighton Profiler",
          body = "Dear Manager, your YSI Profiler failed to complete it's last scheduled profile. Please investigate ASAP.",
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
                      user.name = "example@gmail.com",            
                      passwd = "password", ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

This is the error message:

```
 org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at RJavaTools.invokeMetNULL
hod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout 60000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2053)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:310)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:215)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2019)
    ... 13 more
Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
```

Comment: Please try to add `tls = TRUE` in your smtp list

Comment: @EnriquePérezHerrero This did not work.

Comment: @EnriquePérezHerrero I used sendmailR and worked fine. I'll just stick with this.

Comment: @squarsh: But sendmailR doesn't work with few smtp servers which require authentication.